# How do I avoid "Error Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments." in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, arguments

There is another post that shows this equation, =IF(H6<4.01, 25, IF(H6<5.01, 20, IF(H6<6.01, 15, IF(H6<7.01, 10, IF(H6<8.01, 5, 0))))), as answer to having more than 3 arguments to IF. So when I attempt the following equation, =if(E66, "new Not Used", 0.95,if(E66, "Used Like New", 0.9,if(E66, "Used Great Shape", 0.85,if(E66, "used very good", 0.8,if(E66, "Used Good", 0.75,if(E66, "Used Fair", 0.7,if(E66, "Used Acceptable", 0.65, ""))))))), in the same format I still get "Error Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

What am I doing wrong? Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, trial & Error, I found the error I was doing. I was creating the formula like an excel formula. I found other Sheets formulas with and "=" where the "," was. I see where this was adding arguments. So:
=if(E66, "new Not Used", 0.95,if(E66, "Used Like New", 0.9,if(E66, "Used Great Shape", 0.85,if(E66, "used very good", 0.8,if(E66, "Used Good", 0.75,if(E66, "Used Fair", 0.7,if(E66, "Used Acceptable", 0.65, "")))))))

should be:
=if(e66="New Not Used", 0.95, if(e66="Used Like New", 0.9 ....etc...